# sum of column name using group by in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_RT_GetProdutstogrid]
@purchasedby int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

 select PS.sno, PD.productname,sum(PS.quantity) as quantity,PS.modelno from   K_RT_PurchaseDet PS 
 inner join K_RT_ProductDetails PD on PD.sno=PS.product 
 where purchasedby=@purchasedby and PS.quantity!=0 and attrited='false'

 group by  PD.productname,PS.modelno,PS.company,PS.sno

END
```

by this iam getting out put as

```
sno    product   stock   modelno
1      Computer   2       Dell
2      Mobile     3       Nokia7100
3      Mobile     2       Nokia7100
```

but actually i want out put as

```
sno   product    stock    modelno 
1      Computer   2       Dell
2      Mobile     5       Nokia7100
```

I wrote like this but iam not getting  please help me....

Comment: Do you really want `sno` to be reported incorrectly for 2 Nokia 7100s? if so, does it matter which `sno` value is shown? If you don't actually need the `sno`, then the solution is trivial - see @Akshay's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT MIN(PS.sno) AS sno, 
       PD.productname,
       SUM(PS.quantity) as quantity,
       PS.modelno 
FROM K_RT_PurchaseDet PS 
 JOIN K_RT_ProductDetails PD on PD.sno=PS.product 
 WHERE purchasedby=@purchasedby 
  AND PS.quantity!=0 and attrited='false'
GROUP BY PD.productname,
         PS.modelno,
         PS.company
```

Answer (score 1):

Just edit you `group by` clause in query. Make it to

```
group by PD.productname,PS.modelno
```

Comment: And remove `PS.sno` from the `select`, or SQL Server will complain.